# Is it not possible to construct instances in a loop without a pointer?

Tags: c++

This code will explode, right? As soon as the loop exits, the original instances will die with all their inner members so if they weren't PODs, any method like `do_stuff` which requires access to members of `B` will throw a segmentation fault, correct?

```
void foo() {
  std::vector<B> bar;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    bar.push_back(B(i, i, i));
  bar[3].do_stuff();
}
```

So, is there any way to do this without using a pointer? 
Or do you have to do this:

```
void foo() {
  std::vector<B*> bar;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    bar.push_back(new B(i, i, i));
  bar[3]->do_stuff();
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    delete bar[i];
}
```

Comment: The first way is fine. If you want Java, use `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: also fwiw I don't think "POD" has anything to do with it, its just about life time of the objects. It's not legal to call methods on an object whose lifetime is expired, POD or not

Comment: So weird.. I had the first version, kept getting seg fault => checked with Valgrind, it said it was B::do_stuff() => changed to the second version and now it works fine. Also thought the first version should work. So strage.

Comment: Sounds like your class `B` is broken.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, possible but why would using new B(i..) fix the breakage? Either way, will attempt to get a concise code example that fails (and one that works) if this happens again.

Comment: Because then it no longer uses your class'  broken value semantics. Most likely, your code is violating the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley please elaborate on this with an example on how you can break the code like that? Would be very informative and a really good answer.

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Even if you had to use the second version for some reason, you should use `std::unique_ptr` (to model the ownership) instead of raw `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Post your `B` class and we can probably show you how it's broken.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'd like to do that but it'll break the question (make it unnecessarily convoluted).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - Is it possible, that because class B has a member that doesn't have a default constructor, the copy of an instance is faulty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first code is better than the second one.

The `B` instances will be [**moved**<sup>since C++11</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/3425536)/**copied**<sup>pre-C++11</sup> into the vector, so they will not fall out of scope after the loop — only after the vector falls out of scope.

---

If you want to get the absolutely optimal performance, then do this:

```
void foo() {
  std::vector<B> bar;
  bar.reserve(7);
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    bar.emplace_back(i, i, i);
  bar[3].do_stuff();
}
```

This will guarantee only one reallocation, and the elements are constructed directly inside the vector (instead of moving or copying them there) as per  Marc Glisse's comments.

Comment: If it was C++11, it should use emplace_back and avoid moving at all.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Is moving bad / dangerous?

Comment: @zehelvion No, it is just unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Why? Class B has a huge vector inside it, wouldn't it be much better to move the contents instead of allocating memory twice?

Comment: @zehelvion You are missing the point. It is better to construct things in the right place to begin with, so you don't have to copy or move them.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - No that's the unanswered point, how would you go about filling a vector with n instances of a class that has huge vectors as members without copying or moving?

Comment: That's what I wrote above!!! You use emplace_back to build those instances directly in the vector (and obviously you call reserve(...) first to avoid reallocation, which would cause moves).

Comment: @zehelvion Here's a performance comparison: copying > moving > in-place construction. Moving is essentially an optimization of copy for rvalues, and in-place construction is the fastest if you already know where the constructed elements will end up. See my edited answer.

Comment: @MarcGlisse ,didn't realize what you mean (until now). It sounded (to me) like you were suggesting moving is bad and copying is good and that emplace_back ensures copying. Didn't realize emplace was the solution I've been looking for all this time. Either way, ended up rolling a working copy and move constructor so it thought me a lot. Basically your comment is the answer (with it, we can explicitly forbid copy / move and still have a vector of instances of that class).

Answer (score 12):

The first code example is valid.

`std::vector` will **make a copy** of the objects you pass them with `push_back` (or will **move** them in place with C++11 if you're pushing a temporary) and it will keep all of the instances alive as long as the vector itself is alive.

The destruction will happen when you exit the function, not when you exit the loop.

Comment: "will make a copy", or a __move__. (In this case it would be a move, provided it's compiled as >=C++11.)

Answer (score 4):

No, `std::vector` takes ownership of its members, so the original code will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` copies the objects provided to it (by `push_back()` for example) and keeps them until the the vector itself is destroyed.

So the first code is totally OK as long as the copy constructor of B ( `B(const B&)` )is implemented properly.